# Php If with || not working

Tags: php, if-statement

```
    do  {
    if ($dir[$i] == " " || is_numeric($dir[$i])
        {
        $direccion=$direccion.$dir[$i];
        }
    elseif ($i>6)
        {
        $i=strlen($dir)
        }
    }           
while ($i <= count($dir))
```

$dir is the variable i use to get a google address, but the thing is that it comes with Zip code and City. The thing is that I only need the Street and number.

in the first run `$dir = "Calle 30 433B29938 LaPlataBuenosAiresArgentina"`
And i only need from that 30 433

Since the word " Calle " is always in the return, I've made an if that if its > 6, $i automatically will equal the lenght of the chain and kick me out of the while, because I'll be in "Calle " and there's when the 30 433 begins. The other ifs that I've made, one of them controls if It's a space to add it to the new string $direccion, and the other one checks if It's a number. If it's not a number and if It's not a space and $i > 6, means that I'm in B and I want to finish the do/while.

result of $direccion should be = 30 433. But i get an error on line 3 telling me that there is a problem with a {.

Answer (score 0):

first thing you forget a `)` at the end of your if condition

```
if ($dir[$i] == " " || is_numeric($dir[$i]))
```

and second if you want to get number out of a string you can use

```
   preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
```

like if i use this code

```
    $str = 'Calle 30 433B29938 LaPlataBuenosAiresArgentina ';
    preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
```

output will be

```
   Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 30 [1] => 433 [2] => 29938 ) )
```

But only if you are sure that your string will be exact you defined. 
i am not sure but hope it can help.

Comment: Just to be sure, After using preg_match_all the output will be in $str ? I mean $str[1]=30 ?

Comment: It will be in `$matches`

Comment: Well after doing preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches); $matches[1] is empty

Comment: first tell me, isthe format of your string always same ?

Comment: Yes, its always like that, the only thing that can change is the lenght of the numbers. maybe i get a 1243 instead of 433, or 131 instead of 30, but the order is always like that

Comment: Another output could be $dir="Calle 134 1234B299388 BerissoBuenosAiresArgentina"

Comment: ok then its fine, 
what you can do is 
`$str = $matches[0][0]." ".$matches[0][1];`
simple as it is. 
there are a lot of other ways to do it but i thought it will be the simplest and easy.